# Where do small gas engines get the current for their spark plugs?

Tags: spark

While technically not an EE question, until StackExchange adds a regular Engineering section, EE was the closest fit.

**On small gas engines like those in weed wackers and lawn mowers, where do the spark plugs get the current necessary to create sparks large enough to set fire to the gas fumes?**

Comment: Do they not have alternators?

Comment: No, they have magnetos.

Comment: They use a coil and magnet arrangement driven by the engine (initially by the pull starter).  Really tiny ones - for example model aircraft from before the days of glow ignition - used batteries.

Comment: Ah, effectively the same thing then.

Comment: @Samuel. Neither use batteries" or "use magnets" = alternators in this case. "Use magnets" = magneto which closely times and associates magnet motion with ignition energy storage inductance. You could call it an alternator, much as eg you could call an ambulance a delivery van. And coil ignition + battery <> alternator.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I recall the glow plugs use a big cylindrical 1.5V battery to get the glow plug started, and after that the residual heat in the plug resulted in ignition (if you were lucky). [Cox 0.049](http://cdn.coxengines.ca/images/D/Babe%20Bee%203.jpg) etc. finicky things. Apparently introduced in 1945!

Comment: Yes - platinum wire glow plugs which are electrically heated only for starting, and compatible methanol fuels are the modern solution.  Before that, they used gasoline with battery-powered spark plugs - probably because the battery was lighter/cheaper than a magneto, and they only wanted it to run for a few minutes since they had no radio and had to chase it down.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are other possibilities, but the usual low-tech approach is a magneto.

A permanent magnet is mounted in the flywheel, so that at approximately the right moment, it flies past a pickup coil at high speed, inducing a current in a circuit including that coil. Then, at exactly the right moment, a cam presses a microswitch to open that circuit, interrupting the current.

The resulting dI/dT creates a large V in the primary of a transformer, which is transformed in the secondary to sufficient voltage to make a spark.

As Dave says,there may not be a transformer, just the coil : or the coil itself may be the primary of the transformer, for economy.

Only in the vaguest sense is this the same thing as an alternator : the latter aims to deliver useful quantities of relatively steady power at an approximately constant voltage; the magneto only produces one short pulse per revolution, (sometimes every second revolution in a 4 stroke - the contact breaker can be driven off the camshaft) with no more power than the spark plug needs.

Comment: I've seen 4 stroke engines that fire the spark plug every revolution, twice as much as needed, but the unneeded spark is between the exhaust and intake strokes when there's nothing to burn.  IIRC, there was no switch either.  They were timed entirely by the placement of the magnet on the flywheel and the coil on the block.  You kill it by shorting the coil.

Comment: +1 Light (piston-engine) aircraft typically use dual magnetos with dual plugs- redundant ignition and isolated from anything bad that might happen to the low-voltage electrical system. With the weed wacker type things it's more a matter of avoiding the expense of an electrical system.

Comment: @AaronD: and one of the problems with this approach is not being able to shut off the engine. I have a Murray garden tractor that powers my snowblower. Once the shutoff wire became disconnected and it took me a few weeks to figure out why I couldn't shut the engine off without closing the throttle or clamp the fuel line shut.

Comment: @AaronD : that's why I said "sometimes". Of course there isn't always nothing to burn at that point : if the previous spark missed for some reason, you get a spark with the exhaust valve open and an exhaust full of unburnt mixture ... fun!

Answer (score 3):

Small gas engines have a powerful permanent magnet built into the flywheel, which swings past a coil on each revolution of the crankshaft. This is timed to occur roughly about the time that a spark is needed, and a set of "points" (a switch driven by a cam on the crankshaft) provides the precise timing, opening the circuit and causing the coil to produce a high voltage pulse to the spark plug.

Essentially, the magnet "charges" the coil with energy directly, rather than using the 12V DC bus that you have on larger engines.

Comment: +1 Trigger may be a "reluctor" or other such arcanely named device.

Answer (score 0):

Re: the "wasted" spark of the magneto, mounting the magnet on the flywheel for four stroke engines does produce a wasted spark. This is of no real consequence unless a charge remains unignited from a previous compression stroke. It is just far simpler and more accurate to use the flywheel rather than a reduction gear (cam say). The velocity is greater, there is less lash, and the wiring harness is less cumbersome.

Even non-magneto four stroke engines as still fitted to some motorcycles will have a wasted spark, just because it is simpler and more reliable to run pickups from the flywheel.

Comment: My 200 CC, 4-stroke scooty-puff (basically a vespa) sparks for every revolution, despite the fact that it uses a traditional ignition coil. It's just simpler to design the system that way, and apparently it doesn't create a major issue in terms of spark plug longevity.